# Which nvidia driver from additional drivers option should I choose?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, ppa

I have `NVIDIA Geforece 7025 / nForce 630a` integrated gfx card on my UBUNTU 12.04.And I have 4 options in Additional drivers:

- NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version 173)
- NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates)(version current updates)
- NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version current)[Recommended]
- NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates)(version 173 updates)

I am currently using the First option.

My Problem is there I can't update the version 173 to the latest version of drivers using xswat PPA. Whenever I do it and reboot but the NVIDIA xserver sttings always shows me the same version.

Which option would allow me to update my drivers to the current version?

Comment: If the system go back and don't let you choose the latest driver version is because this are incompatible with your system and prevents you from any harm.

Comment: But sir I have saw on nvidia's website that my gfx card is supported by them ...

Then why my system isn't allowing me to update the drivers to the latest version...???

Comment: [recommended] is recommended

Comment: @Lucio : So sir..did you also faced the same problem as I am facing right now..??

So should I choose the first option and only use the proprietary drivers only..??

Comment: @aking1012: No no... recommended posed a lot of problems ..like freezing graphic malfunction etc... 

SO I switched to the first option ...

Comment: generally, recommended is the best course of action.  if you have a specific bug, file a bug.  [recommended] is targeted to work for the largest number of users with recent hardware.  that's what my comment was about.  not that it would work for you.  it was in hopes that someone with minor problems introduced by a post-release driver would at least try the recommended driver instead (e.g. there was an issue for ATI at one point where the post-release driver failed to install and broke everything, but the recommended driver worked mostly).  i hope you understand the reasoning.

Comment: @aking1012 : Yes Yes... I just installed the recommended version & VOILA ..!!

Version 302 installed ...hurray.. PROBLEM SOLVED ..

Thank you for suggesting RECOMMENDED :)

But how will I make your suggestion as my SOLUTION ..??

Comment: @sud_the_devil were you serious that it solved your problem?  i posted it as a comment since i assumed you had tried it, but posted it for future users...

Comment: I did tried it but when I restarted my PC it was giving me problems   

so I shifted to 173 legacy drivers but today I thought I should try it again..as you told me...

Thank you once again..as I am new here I don't know how to rate your answer ...Sorry :(

But I did edited my post & wrote your name :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[recommended] is recommended

Generally, recommended is the best course of action.

If you have a specific bug, file a bug.

[recommended] is targeted to work for the largest number of users with recent hardware. It may or may not work for this problem.

I post it as an answer in hopes that someone with minor problems introduced by a post-release driver would at least try the recommended driver instead (e.g. there was an issue for ATI at one point where the post-release driver failed to install and broke everything, but the recommended driver worked mostly).

If it solves your problem, great.  If it doesn't, I leave it here as a recommendation for other users to try who insist on edge drivers before trying out the recommended ones.  I hope you understand the reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

Let the built-in ubuntu-drivers program decide automatically which proprietary graphics driver to install. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install   
sudo reboot
```

The `install` option of `ubuntu-drivers` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies. In Ubuntu 20.04 and later running `sudo apt upgrade` not only upgrades the versions of the proprietary graphics drivers that were installed by `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`. Sometimes `sudo apt upgrade` even upgrades the proprietary graphics driver packages to more recent packages, in which case `sudo apt autoremove` removes the older packages which were replaced by the newer ones. For most users there's no reason to guess about which proprietary graphics driver to install, because if your system deserves a graphics driver upgrade it will get one.