# How do I choose which of the offered nvidia drivers is best?

Tags: nvidia, games, jockey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [which nvidia driver from additional drivers option should i choose …?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170898/which-nvidia-driver-from-additional-drivers-option-should-i-choose)

These are the options presented by Jockey:

```
NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version 173)
NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates)(version 173-updates)
NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version current) [Recommended]
NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates)(version current-updates)
```

I have chosen the Recommend one (the third on the list) but due to intermittant unity & system lock ups when changing user or exiting a game, I think a change might be more suitable.

How does the user make sense of these options to make the appropriate choice?