# Which Nvidia driver should I use

Tags: nvidia, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which nvidia driver from additional drivers option should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170898/which-nvidia-driver-from-additional-drivers-option-should-i-choose)

My Laptop is a Toshiba Satellite A660 and my video card is GeForce GT 330M.
I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and I would like to know which Nvidia driver should I install 
current, or current update or 304?

Comment: Use the current one. [Similar questions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/170898/which-nvidia-driver-from-additional-drivers-option-should-i-choose?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I always download straight from Nvidia, and that seems to get me the best results.

http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-304.60-driver.html (32-bit)
http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-304.60-driver.html (64-bit)

Install by first making the file executable:

```
chmod +x ./NVIDIA-Linux[version]
```

Then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open a console terminal. Then type

```
sudo gdm stop
```

Then run the file by changing to its directory and running

```
sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux[version]
```

Follow the prompts, install, then restart by running

```
sudo poweroff -r
```