# Which driver to install for a GeForce GT 520MX graphics card?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation, graphics, steam

I have the following drivers shown on my "Additional drivers" list. I am confused as to which one is stable and usable that doesn't break my system. I use Steam for games. I would like to test few of the games available there.

[image: Additional drivers]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which nvidia driver from additional drivers option should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/170898/which-nvidia-driver-from-additional-drivers-option-should-i-choose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search for the NVIDIA driver for the GeForce GT 520MX graphics card at the [NVIDIA Driver Downloads](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) webpage returned the following result:

[image]

Based on the result from NVIDIA Driver Downloads, the recommended graphics driver to install for your graphics card is nvidia-331 proprietary tested graphics driver. After you have installed nvidia-331 using the Additional Drivers utility and rebooted the computer, you can check your installation in the Additional Drivers utility . There should be a line underneath the graphics card model name that says: *This device is using the recommended driver.*

Comment: But I use a 32-bit Ubuntu :( Any luck? I use 32 bit because I have only 2GB RAM and I feel 32 bit is pretty faster.

Comment: I have edited my answer and changed it as you asked. With 2GB of RAM, I would recommend the nvidia-331 tested driver rather than the nvidia-331-updates driver.