# Nvidia Driver Issue ThinkPad T530

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

I just recently started using Linux on mu old laptop and the first thing that I encountered is that the quality of the picture and text is not as crisp and clean as it was on Windows. I think that this could be a driver issue and but I am having trouble with running the Nvidia drivers in order to find out. After running sudo apt --fix-broken install I still get the message:
Errors were encountered while processing:
nvidia-dkms-390
nvidia-driver-390
I tried all possible solutions that I could find on the Nvidia and Ubuntu forums but still nothing worked. I installed the 525 driver but it did not seem to work. I even tried switching to older kernels to get the old 390 drivers to run but with no success, because I found in a Linux mint forum that the laptop is old. So what I am asking is:

1.Do you think installing and running any Nvidia Driver will improve the quality of the picture at all?
2. If yes is there any point trying to run the old drivers on and older kernel. Will it work at all because some older kernels I downloaded with Mainline do not seem to boot at all?
3. And if i just decide to go for the 525 driver, how do I successfully manage to to install it in order for it to work. Thanks in advance

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details, which are the basic starting point. We need to be told what you're using, as we're limited to information you give us. If you're using a LTS release of Ubuntu, there are kernel stack choices (*default being set by the ISO you choose to install with*), where I have best luck using the GA kernel stack for older hardware, but release details are the starting point for what options exist for you (*and you didn't provide that detail*).

Comment: Hi, Sorry for that, I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
I tried the older stacks from GRUB with no success.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop installs with the HWE kernel stack by default (5.19 for 22.04.2 media, 6.2 for 22.04.3 & 6.5 for 22.04.4 media though on upgrades they'll all be 6.5 now), however Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server & flavors (flavors if 22.04/22.04.1 media is used) will install with GA (5.15), plus OEM options... ie. GA = 5.15, HWE currently is 6.5  (plus OEM), so you've tried each of those?  (*ie. its helpful if you're specific by what you mean with 'older stacks'; I'm skipping OEM options are they're hardware specific & I don't know your hardware sorry*). As stated, GA is often best for older

Comment: I see your point. I downloaded and am now running the GA 5.15 for which the drivers are made however I get the message 

Building for 5.15.0-97-generic 6.5.0-21-generic
Module build for kernel 5.15.0-97-generic was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.

I tried removing the newer kernels from Mainline, however there seems to be a dependency issue and they can not be removed. Should i just purge the headers and try again?

Comment: "kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed": Install `linux-generic` and not directly `linux-image-generic`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which nvidia driver from additional drivers option should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170898/which-nvidia-driver-from-additional-drivers-option-should-i-choose)